# How to ignore part of a url in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I am just setting up an asp.net MVC website to replace an old webforms application and have created a number of different routes to clean the urls so the order information is in the url.

For example

/Order/Payment/JGT058204

Unfortunately this caused the google analytics to stop working because all the urls are now different and all the campaign goals now do not work.

Is there a way in Google analytics to ignore part of the url?

The old site is using Google analytics in Google tag manager and we have limited access to it.

Any help would be amazing.

Cheers

Andy

Comment: What kind of changes to the URL are we talking about, and how different? Please provide examples.

Comment: Each url is now different because they have the order id in them. The users have setup campaigns to match url, for example the payment page (/Order/Payment) but the new url contains the order number (/Order/Payment/JGT058204) and so will not match the url. And because this order id changes for each user we can not just change the url in the campaign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your goal configuration, set them up as Regex match types, and then just add a wildcard match to account for the order ID, for example:

```
^\/Order\/Payment\/.*$
```